# Couldn’t see my test ETH on my Metamask wallet balance

Tags: ether, metamask, testnets, chainlink, faucets

I got funds to my Metamask wallet from Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet to my testnet account and the transaction was sent successfully, status is Success (can see on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/).

Also, can see on my wallet as receive below the balance but the wallet balance is still 0 ETH as you can see on the screenshot.

I have the same problem with the LINK faucet too, can't add tokens to my Metamask balance because couldn't see balance when trying to add it.

Anybody knows how can I fix this problem? I need a test ETH to move on but couldn't do anything at the moment.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: You can check the address in a block explorer to see the balance. It looks like a Metamask issue, did you try using another wallet or installing MM in a different browser?.

Comment: Does this help? [https://docs.chain.link/docs/install-metamask/](https://docs.chain.link/docs/install-metamask/) ?
Make sure that you are selecting the right network at the top of Metamask.

Comment: Are you getting LINK or ETH from the faucet?

Comment: Please share the Txn hash or wallet address so we can take a look at what happened exactly.